# Problems during upgrading from Rails 4.0.0 to 4.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to upgrade from Rails 4.0.0 to 4.1.0 and got an error in application.rb:

```
raw_config = File.read(Rails.root + "./config/settings.yml")
raw_config = YAML.load(raw_config)
```

Error is:

```
uninitialized constant XYZ::Application::YAML (NameError)
```

File.read works, but YAML.load does not.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Thanks :) one second bevore I want to write here I've found it ... but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'yaml'
raw_config = File.read(Rails.root + "./config/settings.yml")
raw_config = YAML.load(raw_config)
```

I'm guessing this worked in Rails 4.0.0 because some other component had already required YAML - and the upgrade changed this behavior.